# how to use axios post method in react js

Tags: reactjs

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPHo5.png)

[getting one response  but want 3 more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZfBi.png)
when i change the channel name i receive another query but not in the program

**Post Method Code**

```
function getPostData() {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayerStatus',
      data: {
        "IpAddress": "",
        "Port": '',
        "ChannelName": "",
        "PlayerName": ""
      },
      headers: {
        "accepts": "application/json",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      Postdata([response.data])
      // Postdata([...Object.values(response.data).flat()]);
      //console.log([...Object.values(response.data).flat()]);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

First, i use the get method to another localhost to fetch channel name now i want to post the method and send the channel name, port, in another URL and there are queries in the image another body i want that to fetch and display it in table row right now i only get channel name 4

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-hoover-4psg4 **link** of full code

Comment: what response / error are you getting ?

Comment: only got 1 response but what 4 responses to fetch

Comment: Your postman screenshot shows a single Properties, that is why your axios gets the same. Do you expect a response with a four length array?

Comment: when i  give   {
    "IpAddress":"192.168.1.1",
    "Port":8133,
     "ChannelName":"Channel1",
    "PlayerName":"Vtr1"
 } and change  *channel name* then response  body change